# Imputing Missing Values in R from reference data frame

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a data frame 'dat' of dim 17000 x 3 of walking data. The interval column is 5 minute intervals for each 24 hour period, the date column is the date and the steps column is the number of steps taken in said 5 minute period on said date. NA's are present.

```
> head(df1)
  steps       date interval
1    NA 2012-10-01        0
2    NA 2012-10-01        5
3    NA 2012-10-01       10
4    NA 2012-10-01       15
5    NA 2012-10-01       20
6    NA 2012-10-01       25
```

I've used *dplyr* to group my df by date and then created a new df 'df.1' and summarized it as avg=mean(df.1$steps, na.rm = TRUE). This gives me a nice little df of the mean value of steps on each date

```
         date      avg
1  2012-10-01      NaN
2  2012-10-02  0.43750
3  2012-10-03 39.41667
4  2012-10-04 42.06944
5  2012-10-05 46.15972
6  2012-10-06 53.54167
```

What I would like to do is update my original df's NA-values with the mean value from each date.

So in the first table where 2012-10-02 was NA then I'd like to replace ever NA value in table one for 2012-10-02 with the value 0.43750. I've tried using indices, which, %in%, apply  family and just can't find anything that is sticking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `merge`.  Also, if you have used `dplyr`, `mutate` would be an option to add the column to the original dataset instead of `summarise`

Comment: So maybe use rownames or index values and merge on like index values?

Comment: May be `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(avg= mean(steps, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: I already have that bit (the mean calculated). What I need is to then update every NA value in original df with the mean value for that given day.

Comment: What I meant is that you don't need to create a second dataset instead you can do this in one step by `mutate`.  If you need to do, then `merge(df1, df1.1, by='date', all=TRUE)` and then change the NA value in steps by the new column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little clunky, but it works:

```
library(dplyr)
df1.1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarise(avg = mean(steps, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    merge(df1, ., all.x=TRUE) %>%
    mutate(steps = ifelse(is.na(steps)==TRUE, avg, steps)) %>%
    select(-avg)
```

Here's my toy data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c(rep("2015-01-01", 12), rep("2015-01-02", 12)), interval = rep(seq(12), 2),
    steps = c(5, 7, NA, 12, 3, NA, 0, 4, 12, 10, 4, 0, 3, NA, 2, 1, NA, 15, 0, 4, 7, 2, NA, 2),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Which looks like:

```
> head(df1)
        date interval steps
1 2015-01-01        1     5
2 2015-01-01        2     7
3 2015-01-01        3    NA
4 2015-01-01        4    12
5 2015-01-01        5     3
6 2015-01-01        6    NA
```

And here's the head of the result, df1.1:

```
> head(df1.1)
        date interval steps
1 2015-01-01        1   5.0
2 2015-01-01        2   7.0
3 2015-01-01        3   5.7
4 2015-01-01        4  12.0
5 2015-01-01        5   3.0
6 2015-01-01        6   5.7
```

Here's a table of the group means to show where those 5.7s come from:

```
> df1 %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(avg = mean(steps, na.rm = TRUE))
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

        date avg
1 2015-01-01 5.7
2 2015-01-02 4.0
```

Comment: I get 'NaN' when I try your approach.

Comment: Huh. It works as shown on the toy data I made to mimic the structure you describe. What happens if you do it step by step? At which step in the piping does it seem to fail?

Comment: It worked really well when going through it one step at a time. I think the pipes may have worked too but I was just focusing on an incorrect subset of the data. Sheesh, I have so much to learn. Your implementation isn't too complicated but I'm very annoyed that I couldn't see it as clearly as you did.

Answer (score 0):

if df1 is your original dataframe and df.1 is the dataframe containing the averages by date, i think a simple for loop could solve it:

```
for(i in df.1$date){
  df1[df1$date==i,"steps"]=df.1[df.1$date==i,"avg"]
}
```

it works for the toy example I just created, I hope it helps.